# C - Creating a projectile 'Hit' or 'Miss' function

Tags: c, simulation

I have created code with a simulation where it records the exact location of a projectile in mid and and after, it prints its covered range and air time.

Users already have the option of selecting their artillery weapon and then applying their inputs via the simulation, but now I have added an additional option where users can select their own type projectile according to my menu.

Basically I want to know how I can get the user's target distance and say whether the projectile has hit the target or missed it completely with the blast radius values shown in the projectile selection menu.

I also would like the hit or miss printed at the end of the simulation (end of program).

**Here is my full source:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.14159265358979323846
#define GRAVITY 9.8
#define ANGLE_RAD45 0.7853981634


typedef struct Artillery
{
    char name[30];
    float muzzleVelocity;
    float minAngleOfElevation;
    float maxAngleOfElevation;
}Artillery;


typedef struct Projectile
{
    char name[30];
    double blastRadius;
}Projectile;


// Function header: artillery struct
void PrintArtillery(Artillery artillery);

// Function header: projectile struct
void PrintProjectile(Projectile projectile);

// Function header: max range
double CalculateRange(double velocity, double angle);

// Function header: deg to rad angle conversion
double AngleDegToRad(double angle);

// Function header: air time
double CalculateAirTime(double velocity, double angle);

// Function header: simulate projectile location
void SimulateProjectile(double* height, double* distance, double time, double velocity, double angle);


int main(void)
{
    // Variables
    int userValue;
    int userValueTwo;
    double userTargetDist;

    double angleRad;
    double userAngle;
    double maxRange;
    double airTime; 

    double cannonMaxR = 200;
    double howitzMaxR = 900;
    double mortarMaxR = 805;

    double simHeight; //passive variable
    double simDistance;
    double simTime;


    // Array of 3 weapons
    Artillery weapon[3];

    // Generate weapons
    weapon[0] = (Artillery) { "Cannon", 200, 0, 45 };
    weapon[1] = (Artillery) { "Howitzer", 900, 20, 65 };
    weapon[2] = (Artillery) { "Mortar", 805, 50, 85 };

    // Print title of artillery menu    
    printf("\n|Artillery Weapon\t|Muzzle Velocity\t|Min Elevation\t\t|Max Elevation\n");
    printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        PrintArtillery(weapon[i]);
    }

    printf("Please select an artillery weapon (1, 2 or 3)\n");
    scanf("%i", &userValue);

    while(userValue < 1 || userValue > 3)
    {
        printf("Input is invalid\nPlease use the appropriate values to select your gun (1, 2, 3)\n");
        scanf("%i", &userValue);
        fflush(stdin);
    }


    // Array of 3 shells
    Projectile ammoType[3];

    // Generate ammo types
    ammoType[0] = (Projectile) { "High Explosive Anti-Tank", 5 };
    ammoType[1] = (Projectile) { "M549 HERA             ", 15 };
    ammoType[2] = (Projectile) { "W19 Katie AFAP        ", 4200 };

    // Print title of projectile menu
    printf("\n|Projectile Shell\t\t|Blast Radius\n");
    printf("-------------------------------------------\n");

    // Loop data
    int ii;
    for(ii = 0; ii < 3; ii++)
    {
        PrintProjectile(ammoType[ii]);
    }

    // Ask user to selection shell
    printf("Please select a shell (1, 2 or 3)\n");
    scanf("%i", &userValueTwo);

    // Apply warning when input is invalid
    while(userValueTwo < 1 || userValueTwo > 3)
    {
        printf("Input is invalid\nPlease use the appropriate values to select your shell (1, 2, 3)\n");
        scanf("%i", &userValueTwo);
        fflush(stdin);
    }


// HOW DO I USE USER'S TARGETDIST TO SHOW HIT OR MISS AT THE END OF SIMULATION???


// Ask user for distance to target in m
printf("Please enter the distance to the target in metres\n");
scanf("%lf", &userTargetDist);


// Make decisions after verified user's inputs
switch(userValue)
{   
    case 1:

        // Start calc after verified ans
        // Run max range func (tells max range of gun)
        maxRange = CalculateRange(mortarMaxR, angleRad);

        // Print instructions
        printf("Please enter the angle of elevation in degrees\n"); 

        scanf("%lf", &userAngle);

        // Validate user input          
        while(userAngle < 0 || userAngle > 45)
        {
            printf("Input is invalid\nThe angle of elevation must be between 50.00 to 85.00 degrees\n");
            scanf("%lf", &userAngle);
            fflush(stdin);
            continue;
        }   

        // Start calc after verified answers
        if(userAngle > 0 || userAngle < 45)
        {   
            // Run deg to rad angle conversion func
            angleRad = AngleDegToRad(userAngle);

            // Run air time func
            airTime = CalculateAirTime(mortarMaxR, angleRad);       

            // Sim loop starts here (track proj location)
            for(simTime = 1; simTime <= airTime; simTime++)
            {
                SimulateProjectile(&simHeight, &simDistance, simTime, mortarMaxR, angleRad);
            }

            // Print total distance travelled & total air time
            printf("The projectile has hit ground level!\nTotal distance travelled: %f\nTotal air time: %f\n", simDistance, airTime);}  

        break;



    case 2:

        // Run max range func (tells max range of gun)
        maxRange = CalculateRange(howitzMaxR, angleRad);

        // Print instructions
        printf("Please enter the angle of elevation in degrees\n"); 

        scanf("%lf", &userAngle);

        // Validate user input          
        while(userAngle < 20 || userAngle > 65)
        {
            printf("Input is invalid\nThe angle of elevation must be between 20.00 to 65.00 degrees\n");
            scanf("%lf", &userAngle);
            fflush(stdin);
            continue;
        }   

        // Start calc after verified answers
        if(userAngle > 20 || userAngle < 65)
        {   
            // Run deg to rad angle conversion func
            angleRad = AngleDegToRad(userAngle);

            // Run air time func
            airTime = CalculateAirTime(howitzMaxR, angleRad);       

            // Sim loop starts here (track proj location)
            for(simTime = 1; simTime <= airTime; simTime++)
            {
                SimulateProjectile(&simHeight, &simDistance, simTime, howitzMaxR, angleRad);
            }

            // Print total distance travelled & total air time
            printf("The projectile has hit ground level!\nTotal distance travelled: %f\nTotal air time: %f\n", simDistance, airTime);
        }   

        break;      



    case 3:

        // Run max range func (tells max range of gun)
        maxRange = CalculateRange(mortarMaxR, angleRad);

        // Print instructions
        printf("Please enter the angle of elevation in degrees\n"); 

        scanf("%lf", &userAngle);

        // Validate user input          
        while(userAngle < 50 || userAngle > 85)
        {
            printf("Input is invalid\nThe angle of elevation must be between 50.00 to 85.00 degrees\n");
            scanf("%lf", &userAngle);
            fflush(stdin);
            continue;
        }   

        // Start calc after verified answers
        if(userAngle > 50 || userAngle < 85)
        {   
            // Run deg to rad angle conversion func
            angleRad = AngleDegToRad(userAngle);

            // Run air time func
            airTime = CalculateAirTime(mortarMaxR, angleRad);       

            // Sim loop starts here (track proj location)
            for(simTime = 1; simTime <= airTime; simTime++)
            {
                SimulateProjectile(&simHeight, &simDistance, simTime, mortarMaxR, angleRad);
            }

            // Print total distance travelled & total air time
            printf("The projectile has hit ground level!\nTotal distance travelled: %f\nTotal air time: %f\n", simDistance, airTime);
        }   

        break;  
}

return 0;
}   


//-----FUNCTION CALCULATIONS-----//

// Function calculation: artillery struct
void PrintArtillery(Artillery artillery)
{
    // Print variables of artillery menu
    printf("|%s   \t\t|%f m/s\t\t\|%f deg\t\t\t|%f deg\t\n\n",  artillery.name, 
                                                                artillery.muzzleVelocity, 
                                                                artillery.minAngleOfElevation, 
                                                                artillery.maxAngleOfElevation);
}

// Function calculation: projectile struct
void PrintProjectile(Projectile projectile)
{
    // Print variables of projectile menu
    printf("|%s\t|%lf metres\n\n",   projectile.name, projectile.blastRadius);
}

// Function calculation: max range
double CalculateRange(double velocity, double angle)
{
    double maxRange;
    maxRange = (velocity*velocity/GRAVITY)*sin(2*ANGLE_RAD45);
    printf("Maximum range: %.2lf\n", maxRange);
    return maxRange;
}

// Function calculation: deg to rad angle conversion
double AngleDegToRad(double angle)
{
    double angleRad;
    angleRad = angle*(PI/180);
    return angleRad;
}

// Function calculation: air time
double CalculateAirTime(double velocity, double angle)
{
    double airTime;
    airTime = (2*velocity*sin(angle))/GRAVITY;
    return airTime;
}

// Function calculation: projectile location sim
void SimulateProjectile(double* height, double* distance, double time, double velocity, double angle)
{
    *height = (velocity*time)*sin(angle)-(0.5*GRAVITY*(time*time));
    *distance = (velocity*time)*cos(angle);
    printf("At %f second(s), height is: %f and distance is: %f\n", time, *height, *distance);
}
```

Comment: By solving the equation of motion for height = 0? Then compare with target distance. Or to be cheeky, do a linear interpolation to get the distance between two of your plots that straddle the target's height. If that's too gross, make your sample time smaller, and recalculate the plots between the two that straddle the target's height. Or you could make a recursive function that halves the time interval between each plot, until the pair that straddle the target has a suffiently small separation, that a linear interpolation is acceptable.

Comment: Could you put your theory into practice?